# How to get back unversioned folder back which were deleted by Subversion

Tags: linux, svn, restore

I use linux OS. I was working on a local copy of folder : test_scripts. This was not version-ed in SVN. As I wanted to checkinto SVN, I made entry:

cd to my local folder:

```
# svn add test_scripts
```

Then realized it made entry to some of unwanted files inside test_script folder. I deleted those files on my local, & tried to commit. Commit failed as there was change in local copy. So I thought of deleting the entry in svn for the folder test_script to redo fresh. so I used:

```
# svn --force delete test_scripts/
```

This deleted my local copy too! :-(

I have no back up & all my work is gone..

Please can some one help me how to get back deleted local file in linux. Its very important !..

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is "you can't", unfortunately.

There are tools which *might* try to help you provided your filesystem has plenty of free space and received low write activity since you've deleted that directory.

[Google for "ext2+undelete"](https://www.google.com/search?q=ext2+undelete), and it will bring you a couple of tools like `TestDisk`, `e2undel` etc.